# How do different monitoring tools calculate memory bandwidth?

Tags: performance, intel, amd-processor, intel-pmu, memory-bandwidth

For monitoring memory bandwidth, there is pcm-memory on the Intel platform and AMDuProf on the AMD platform.

**How do they calculate memory bandwidth usage? Which PMUs were used?**

**Is it using 1024 or 1000 base for GB/MB/KB calculation?** I think 1000 base is more suitable, but I'm not sure.